# Toolbar is displayed twice in coordinate layout fragment

Tags: android

And I used `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`

but here toolbar is transparent.

[image]

Am using above XML layout I fragment because my requirement is I need different layout in fragment. Any help will be appreciated.

> ToolBar Issue in cordinatelayout

```
Here is my code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop_BannerImage_Id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/grass_background"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_event_home_Id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/cast_expanded_controller_actionbar_bg_gradient_light"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_name_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_date_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/event_name_text_view"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:text="21-08-2016"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_attendee_count_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_name_text_view"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:text="1000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <!-- <Button
                         android:id="@+id/event_book_now_button"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@id/event_date_text_view"
                         android:layout_margin="15dp"
                         android:background="@color/primary"
                         android:text="Book Now"
                         android:textColor="@color/background_color" />-->

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_view_line"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/event_attendee_count_text_view"
                        android:background="#cccccc" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sub_linearLayout_1_day_id"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/event_info_view_line"
                        android:layout_margin="15dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_info_day_time_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_info_day_text_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:text="21-08-2016" />
                        <!--<TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_info_days_text_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="2 days"
                            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"/>-->

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sub_linearLayout_2_place_id"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/sub_linearLayout_1_day_id"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_info_location_icon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_info_location_text_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:text="21-08-2016" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/map_event_info"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/sub_linearLayout_2_place_id"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"></FrameLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_details_header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="Details"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_details_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingButtonEventInfoId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingButtonEventInfoFeedBackId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingButtonEventInfoShareId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

yours toolbar background is messing with yours collapsingtoolbarlayout

```
 android:background="@drawable/cast_expanded_controller_actionbar_bg_gradient_light"
```

Try to remove it and run.

Comment: I solved it.Problem was one more coordinate layout was there in MainActivity.Thanks for ur response.